# how to view an object(from ts file) in ion slides

Tags: angular, spring-boot, ionic3

I want to show details from an object in ion-slides based on my selection of segments. Here I have an object(obj) passed through from another component using NavParam.
"Condition" is is one of the fields in "myDetails", it holds values(unfit, Fit, and Qualified)

```
// this is from my ts file
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Loading, LoadingController, Slides } from 'ionic-angular';
.....
.....


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-manager-details',
  templateUrl: 'manager-details.html',
})
export class CrewManagerDetailsPage {

  @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private crewProvider: 
  CrewProvider, public navParams: NavParams,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public utils: UtilsModule) {

      this.obj = this.navParams.data.myDetails;
    console.log(this.navParams.data);}      }


ionViewDidLoad() {
this.obj = this.navParams.data.myDetails;

      for (let newData of this.obj ) {

        if (newData.condition == 'unfit') {
          this.canBeRostered.push(newData);
        }
        if (newData.condition == 'Fit') {
          this.notMedicalFit.push(newData);
        }
        if (newData.condition == 'Qualified') {
          this.notQualified.push(newData);
        }
        if (newData.condition == 'Default') {
          this.default.push(newData);
        }
      };
}
```

this is my html file

```
<div>
      <ion-slides  pager="true">
        <ion-slide *ngFor ="let dtls of obj">
          <h2>lets </h2>
          <h2>({{dtls .name}})</h2>
          <h3>Grade:
            <b>{{dtls .grade}}</b>
          </h3>
          <h3>Sign On Date:
            <b>{{dtls .date}}</b>
          </h3>
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides> 
    </div>
```

I want to see a list of my object(obj) details in the ion-slides. When I run my application now I can clearly see that the slide has generated a correct number of slides(7) according to the data that my object(obj) returns, however, the data doesn't show on the slides.

Comment: The spaces between the dtls and the dots looks wrong to start - in your HTML `dtls .name` ->`dtls.name`  (x3) etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is space between the dot`(.)` and object `dtls` object so just replace below code it will work.

```
<div>
      <ion-slides  pager="true">
        <ion-slide *ngFor ="let dtls of obj">
          <h2>lets </h2>
          <h2>({{dtls.name}})</h2>
          <h3>Grade:
            <b>{{dtls.grade}}</b>
          </h3>
          <h3>Sign On Date:
            <b>{{dtls.date}}</b>
          </h3>
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides> 
    </div>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: @JGFMK i have removed the spaces and the main issue is that when i use "dtls.name", "dtls.grade", "dtls.date"  i do not get the actual values returned to my view. when i run the app i just see the hardcoded "texts" which is "lets","()", "Grade:" , "Sign On Date:"  .

Comment: please check if data is coming or not using consol.log(obj);

Comment: thanks for your advice i managed to trace my issue and fixed it. i have  looped through each item and added an ion-item in between ion-slide tags for displaying my data. thanks a lot

Comment: @JGFMK thanks a lot for your advice my code works now.